# Images not displaying as background images on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone explain why my images aren't displaying on my test web page? 
Do I have to set height/widths on the div to show the full image?

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/t2nwevgL/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.row div {
  background:blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="background:url('http://placehold.it/480x480') 0 0 no-repeat"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="background:url('http://placehold.it/480x480') 0 0 no-repeat"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="background:url('http://placehold.it/480x480') 0 0 no-repeat"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: You need to set the height of the elements because if divs are empty the height will be 0.

Comment: you have to set min-height: 500px or other. and set height: auto;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With Bootstrap, how would you suggest I set the height. Should I set it to 480 then change for each breakpoint? Or is there a standard way of doing this? Thank you

Comment: `.row div div { height: 480px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set height and width of elemenets and display block

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="img" style="background:url('http://placehold.it/480x480') 0 0 no-repeat"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="img" style="background:url('http://placehold.it/480x480') 0 0 no-repeat"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="img" style="background:url('http://placehold.it/480x480') 0 0 no-repeat"></div>

      </div>

    </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->


//css 

.img{
  width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Divs have display set to block by default.

Answer (score 2):

Give the divs a specific height such as `height: 500px;` or `height: 100vh;` <-- (to fill the size of the viewport), and they will show the background image. If the div doesn't contain any content, then the height of the div is 0, because the background image doesn't affect the height of the div.

If you put a `<p>` tag with filler text and don't specify the height, you'll see that the div is only as high as the content.